# Boot Read Only Debian With Some Exceptions

Tags: linux, debian, embedded-linux

I have an embedded system booting Debian off from a CF card. To minimize the potential for unrecoverable corruption when non-graceful shutdowns occur, I can boot the filesystem readonly by configuring it in fstab. However, there are a handful of directories that I would like to keep read/ write. How do I keep most of my filesystem readonly with a few exceptions?

For example /dev/hda1 mounted at / is my CF card which is readonly. I have a directory, /root (within /) in which I want to be read/write.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mount a filesystem "partially read-write," that makes no sense.  You will have to move the directories you want to keep writable to...

- Separate individual volumes, and mount them separately, or
- One separate volume, mount it, and then `mount --bind` the directories where they belong.

Comment: You can do "partially write" with a union overlay of some sort

Comment: Yes, but I have yet to find a decent, stable, and widely-supported union filesystem (which is a real shame) and therefore I don't feel comfortable recommending one.

Comment: That's fine for directories where I want everything to be read-write. However, the issue is that I might want to let the user make edits to /etc/network/interfaces but nothing else in /etc. How do I pull this off?

Comment: @kittyhawk By setting an appropriate permissions mask, presumably.  You can also use `chattr +i` on individual files to make them read-only, *even to root*.  Of course, root can `chattr -i` at any time to remove the flag.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at Voyage Linux, it's a Debian distribution specially made to run on embedded devices.
On /etc/default/voyage-util you can configure which directories are mounted rw (on RAM) and Voyage syncs them to CF on reboot

http://linux.voyage.hk/